# Hide buy button first and show it later

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I have various products in my app to buy already added in-app purchase too. But I need the user to see all the products first without buy button and if user selects one product after opening app first time, He will get that product for free and remaining product will display buy button.

My question is that Does App Store rejects for these kind of behavior? If yes then how can I handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

No Apple doesn't rejects such functionality.
// All you need to do is hide the buy button in viewDidLoad.

buyBtn.hidden = true;

and then on click of product or wherever you want to display the buy button,

// unhide button.

buyBtn.hidden = false;